# Unslider animateHeight not showing first slide

Tags: jquery, html, unslider

For some reason when setting the option animateHeight to true, the first slide does not show. The slide is not shown, but it's there. If I skip forward a slide and back again, it appears as it should do.

Has anyone else encountered this? See screenshots below.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZGP.gif) shows the result after initiation. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lRx.gif) shows the result after skipping forward and back a slide. (Content scribbled out)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.my-slider').unslider({
    animateHeight: true,
    nav: false,
    arrows: {
      prev: '<i style="color:#333" class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>',
      next: '<i style="color:#333;float:right" class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i>'
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by manually setting the height of the first slide using CSS.

I'm not sure whether it's a bug in the unslider.min.js file.